# How to create a 3D figure with turtle graphic style commands

Tags: python, modeling

I'm new with Blender and I want to know if Blender has some "Turtle Graphics" style box.

I mean: the old Logo programming language used some commands like:

```
SETX=100 (put the cursor at X=100),
SETY=100 (put the cursor at Y=100),
FORWARD 45 (move the cursor 45 steps forward),
RIGHT 90 (change the forward direction to the right, 90 degrees)`,
```

etc.

Is there something like this in Blender?

Comment: You want to achieve it using the modeling tools or a script? If you want to simulate this kind of functionality you may add a curve with some Depth value and keep extruding it inputting the desired parameters. Otherwise you may need to create a specific script/add-on for that. BTW thanks for reminding me this program. Spent some time playing with it on my Atari 800XL as a child :)

Comment: Good old days! My first thought was the [Profile Node](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues/350#issuecomment-51353886) (thanks @zeffi) in [Sverchok add-on](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Nodes/Sverchok), but it is currently more coordinates-oriented (so I think you'll not be able to rotate the turtle)

Comment: Hahaha!!! I also used Logo with Atari XL/XE, and I still use one of the last computing universe version, called ElicaLogo. Unfortunately, Logo is still an interpreted language (you need an external compiler to get an "executable"). Blender could has something like that (there is some graphic software with it, but I don't remember its name). I'm talking about a box with the parameters for x, y and z of each point of the 3D figure, and others capabilities to animate it. Is there? Where? Thanks a lot for your time!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Blender User Interface is written in Python, and Python 3.4 is included in the most recent (2.76b as of this writing) distribution of Blender. I see from [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) that Python has up through release 3.5 included an implementation of Turtle graphics, so the answer to your question is a qualified "Yes", though it might be that you have to do some fiddling around with the Python implemented in Blender to obtain this capability.